# usb 3.0 controller xhci driver not setup

Tags: drivers, usb, qemu

I have purchased a cheap usb 3.0 controller on Ebay based on the VIA VL805,I have tested it on a dell OEM motherboard and it works fine.

But now on my gigabyte 990FXA-ud3 it not works, the xhci driver is not setup :

```
02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1106:3483] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1106:3483]
03:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1106:3483] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1458:5007]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

as you can see my motherboard uses the same chip as the cheap controller, it's a pure coincidence. The cheap one is situated on bus 2

my dmesg indicates this error :

```
dmesg | grep xhci
[    1.257762] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.258353] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 8
[   17.466094] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: can't setup: -110
[   17.466913] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: USB bus 8 deregistered
[   17.466949] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: init 0000:02:00.0 fail, -110
[   17.466963] xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -110
[   17.467016] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[   17.467020] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 8
[   17.467135] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 quirks 0x00000090
[   17.467240] usb usb8: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic xhci-hcd
[   17.467405] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[   17.467407] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 9
[   17.467441] usb usb9: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic xhci-hcd
[   17.800067] usb 8-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

The problem is I want to use this controller to allocate it to a virtual machine (passtrough), but when I do this, the VM takes a while to boot and finally has the same dmesg return, so I think the problem come from here.

How can I solve this issue ?

Thank by advance for your answers :)